# Use cookie to save the login information,but for android platform it cannot work

Tags: android, angularjs, cookies, onsen-ui, monaca

I use onsen-ui and angularjs to achieve a login function on Monaca, actually it works well when I debug on iphone and preview on the website, but when I try to use it on a android system, i find that cookies are not saved. The next time I access the login page, what I see is a welcome page, but on the android system, the system asked me to log in again.
When I login success , I save my information on cookie.
My code as follows:

```
$scope.login = function(){  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'https://www.xxxxxxx.com/api/public/user_login',
        data:{
            username:document.getElementById('login_username').value, 
            password:document.getElementById('login_password').value
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.error != "" & data.error != null ){
                alert(data.error); 
                delCookie('username');                  
            }else if(data.status == 0){
                setCookie('username',data.username,365);
                $scope.username = getCookie('username');
                document.getElementById('loginInfo').style.display="none";
                document.getElementById('welcome').style.display="block";
            }
        },
    });
};
function getCookie(login_name){
if (document.cookie.length>0){ 
    login_start=document.cookie.indexOf(login_name + "=")
    if (login_start!=-1){ 
        login_start=login_start + login_name.length+1; 
        login_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",login_start);
        if (login_end==-1){
            login_end=document.cookie.length;
        }
        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(login_start,login_end));
    } 
}
return "";
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays){
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+((expiredays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toGMTString());
}

function  delCookie(name){
var  exp  =  new  Date();
exp.setTime  (exp.getTime()  -  1);
var  cval  =  getCookie (name);
document.cookie  =  name  +  "="  +  cval  +  ";  expires="+  exp.toGMTString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$cookieStore` it seems deprecated now, instead `'$cookie is the one we need to use.

Instead of using the `document.cookie`, which is a web API, use the angular inbuilt service for the same, you won't have difficulties with this in android and ios.

You need to just inject the dependency in your controller:

as:

```
angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('AuthController', function ($scope,
                                        $cookies,//injecting the dependency here
                                        $timeout,
                                        ngDialog) {


$scope.login = function(){  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'https://www.xxxxxxx.com/api/public/user_login',
        data:{
            username:document.getElementById('login_username').value, 
            password:document.getElementById('login_password').value
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.error != "" & data.error != null ){
                alert(data.error); 
                delCookie('username');                  
            }else if(data.status == 0){
                setCookie('username',data.username,365);
                $scope.username = getCookie('username');
                document.getElementById('loginInfo').style.display="none";
                document.getElementById('welcome').style.display="block";
            }
        },
    });
};
function getCookie(login_name){
if (document.cookie.length>0){ 
    login_start= document.cookie.indexOf(login_name + "=")
    //use $cookies.get(login_name) to get value of the login_name param set in cookie
    if (login_start!=-1){ 
        login_start=login_start + login_name.length+1; 
        login_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",login_start);
       //use $cookies.get(login_name) to get value of the login_name param set in cookie
        if (login_end==-1){
            login_end=document.cookie.length;
            //use $cookies.get(login_name) to get value of the login_name param set in cookie
        }
        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(login_start,login_end));
    } 
}
return "";
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays){
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+((expiredays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toGMTString());
//use $cookies.put(key, value) to get value of the login_name param set in cookie
}

function  delCookie(name){
var  exp  =  new  Date();
exp.setTime  (exp.getTime()  -  1);
var  cval  =  getCookie (name);
document.cookie  =  name  +  "="  +  cval  +  ";  expires="+  exp.toGMTString();
//use $cookies.put(key, value) to get value of the login_name param set in cookie
}


}
```

It's easy to implement and use, please refer the [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore) for the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. After I use the $cookies, but it also cannot save cookies on Android system. And there was a new problem,data on the Android platform to show is undefined, but in ios system is able to display.

Comment: I solve this problem by using a factory to save the login information.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good Pal... just wished to let you know.. you can use local storage too, to save the data in your device browser/web view, we use the same in our project, earlier we were using the cookiestore, but there the data can't be kept longer by cookies, local storage is recommended for that functionality.

Comment: That's good, I'm just learning these, I am not very familiar. Thanks a lot for your help.